# Is it possible to share a private Swift framework between CocoaPod submodules?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm building an SDK that has a "Core" module, and a number of optional al-a-carte Submodules.  I'd like to deliver it using Cocoapods and their submodule functionality much in the same way as the iOS Firebase SDK:

- SDK

  - Submodule-A
  - Submodule-B

So that developers can `pod 'SDK'` and get all of the submodules, or `pod 'SDK/Submodule-A'` and just get the core SDK + any selected submodules.  Similar to how you can get `Firebase/Auth` or `Firebase/Database` or get the whole thing with just `Firebase`.  Unlike Firebase however, I'd like to keep the source code private (By packaging `vendored-frameworks`), and also unlike Firebase the code is Swift.

The challenge I have is that there are some shared "Core" elements and classes whose API I would like to keep private from those who import the SDK (Internal shared network code, etc) but be able to share a single instance of among any present Submodules, and I would like this code to live in the SDK "Core" so that it could be accessed and shared by any submodules.

This used to be possible in Objective C by the "Hack" of using private categories, but Swift is stricter.

Is it possible to share a private Swift framework between CocoaPod submodules?

Answer (score 1):

I can't confirm this is a verbatim answer (not a fan of CocoaPods, so my knowledge is slightly lacking about all of its capabilities), but I'm fairly confident in what I have to share.

This sounds a lot like the concept of wanting to be able to unit test private properties and functions in Swift. The simple answer to for this is that you can't. Something that's private to a Swift module is strictly private, and since unit tests are a separate module, they cannot access anything less permissive than symbols marked as `public` without importing the tested module with the `@testable` attribute (which only provides access to `internal` level symbols at the lowest).

The less simple answer to that is that you would then test those private methods through the symbols you CAN access (or sacrifice the private level for the sake of testing), and by confirming that the accessible symbols are functioning correctly, you can safely assume the private ones are supporting them adequately.

Without knowing more about your project, I can't say if that last bit is helpful to you or not at all.

It also sounds like you understand that privacy scopes in Objective C aren't really enforced so much as *politely requesting* that you don't touch them, ultimately doing nothing to stop you from doing so.

...

Maybe this approach would work for you (I can neither confirm nor deny if this would be a best practice, but I think it would work):

Create a module called `MyFramework-Private` that has everything you want to mask from the user, but with all shared methods and properties at a `public` level. Import that into any module you want to ultimately be user facing, but don't include that in the instructions for the developer to include. This wouldn't STOP a user from accessing that module, but it would make it clear that it's not supported, nor recommended. So `MyFramework-Database` would import `MyFramework-Private`, but the user would only import `MyFramework-Database` and only be exposed to whatever's public (or open) in the *Database* portion.

Comment: This is basically where I was at when I asked... The answer that you can't share swift modules internal or private functionality between modules seems to be consistent with the places where I've checked regarding Unit Tests (which are trying to do something similar but not quite the same as my ask here).  That being said, sharing a module (even nested) with a public API puts that API into the auto-generated interface (where it needs to be for other modules to access it).  I'll leave this as unanswered for now as there may be a way that we aren't aware of.

Comment: Responding to: "That being said, sharing a module (even nested) with a public API puts that API into the auto-generated interface"...            It shouldn't (although, I haven't explicitly tested with CocoaPods to be certain). My own framework, QRettyCode (QRC), depends on another project of mine called SwiftyBinaryFormatter (SBF). When importing QRC into whatever app I'm developing, I don't have access to any public symbols in SBF without explicitly importing SBF in addition to QRC, despite explicit imports for SBF inside QRC. To be fair, I used Carthage to test and confirm this, so ymmv.

Comment: I apologize for the poorly formatted comment. Apparently newlines and markdown are ignored in comments.

Comment: I think I figured it out, and it's something similar to adding a module.  However there was some pain around nested submodules (no framework in a framework) which required a little finesse.  I'll document as an answer once I'm happy with the outcome.